# Why aren't my iptables rules appearing in the relevant list after reboot?

Tags: debian, networking, iptables, nat

I am trying to write two persistent NAT rules, which I save via `iptables-save > /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat`, and restore upon reboot via `pre-up iptables-restore < /etc/iptables.ipv4.nat` in my `/etc/network/interfaces`. Prior to reboot, the rules display when `iptables -t nat -L` is used, but after reboot the rules seem to return to their default. Curiously, when I inspect the file to which I saved the rules, they are still present.

So what's happening, and how do I fix it (if it requires fixing at all)?

Comment: Can you check for errors on the `pre-up` line, and see if running the `iptables-restore` manually works as expected?

Comment: Is it possible that a file permission on the saved file is causing you trouble?

Comment: Apologies for the late reply! I could find no errors on the `pre-up` line, but running `iptables-restore` manually did work as expected.

Comment: As a workaround, I've written the `iptables-restore` command to `/etc/rc.local` instead, but I'd still be interested to know why my original method didn't work as expected. 
I also tried writing the rules out in `/etc/network/interfaces` rather than using save and restore, and that didn't work either, so maybe it's a problem with that file?

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the package

```
apt-get install iptables-persistent
```

in order to make your changes persistent.

In order to save your current settings use

```
/etc/init.d/iptables-persistent save
```

Next time you boot, the settings will be restored.